# In Windows Forms what's the easiest way to get the control(s) over which another control is placed?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I'm not interesting in finding the parent control. I'm interested in finding a reference to the control or controls on top of which a given control is placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rectangle.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kh3ee9e.aspx)

```
if (control1.Bounds.Contains(control2.Bounds))
{
    //control1 contains control 2.
}
```

You can use this logic to find reference of control or controls on top of which a given control is placed.